# Invalid form of pragma atomic

Tags: c, openmp

My goal is to use either atomic or critical in openMP and achieve the same result as when I use firstprivate(state) in the following code, but the compiler is throwing me with an invalid form error for omp atomic.

Here is the code:

```
        omp_set_dynamic(0);
        omp_set_num_threads(threads[y]);
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count) private(i)
        for(i=1;i<=niter;i++){
            double x, y, z;
            long seed;
            seed=i;
            #pragma omp atomic
            x=ran2(&seed, &state);
            #pragma omp atomic
            y=ran2(&seed, &state);
            #pragma omp atomic
            z=x*x+y*y;
            if(z<1){
                count+=1;
            }
        }
```

**The expected output is:**

```
The value of pi for 1 threads is 3.14320000000000
The value of pi for 2 threads is 3.13320000000000
The value of pi for 4 threads is 3.12400000000000
The value of pi for 8 threads is 3.14680000000000
The value of pi for 16 threads is 3.15880000000000
```

But am not getting the same? Any directions to get the same?

Comment: This question would be improved if you include the complete error message that you get from the compiler (not a paraphrasing of it).  And, since you show expected output, you should include the code generates the output.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify an *atomic-clause* in your `omp atomic` construct, it will assume you want to `update`.  You expression statements are not update statements.

What you should use for your omp directive is

```
#pragma omp atomic write
```

However, since `x`, `y`, and `z` are all local variables, each thread will have its own copy and the atomic construct is not needed.  It will not work to make calls to `ran2` atomic; only the assignment of the result will be.

Answer (score 1):

> the compiler is throwing me with an invalid form error for omp atomic.

The `atomic` pragma is not freely applicable to any statement whatever.  Only specific forms of statements are permitted, dependent on which flavor of atomic clause you use.  If you do not specify a flavor, then you get the "update" flavor, which requires an expression statement (so far so good) with one of the following forms:

```
x++;
x--;
++x;
--x;
x binop= expr;
x = x binop expr;
x = expr binop x;
```

, where `binop` represents one of the operators `+`, `*`, `-`, `/`, `&`, `ˆ`, `|`, `<<`, or `>>`.  There are more requirements as well; see section 2.13.6 of [the OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf).  None of the statements you're trying to declare atomic satisfy those requirements.

> But am not getting the same? Any directions to get the same?

The above accounts for the warnings, but even if those forms were allowed, you seem to have greater expectations for `atomic` than OpemMP satisfies.  For a well-formed atomic operation, it is the access to a specific memory location -- designated by `x` in the above -- that is atomic, not execution of the whole statement.  Your `x`, `y`, and `z` are already private, so updating them atomically gains you nothing.  With `state` being a shared variable, however, (in contrast to when you declared it `firstprivate`) you have race conditions involving accesses to it, and your program's behavior is therefore undefined.

I suppose your expected results are drawn from your alternative code in which `state` is declared `firstprivate`, but even if your accesses to `state` were properly synchronized -- by putting them in `omp critical` sections, for example -- it would not be reasonable to expect the same results, because you would be performing a different computation.  Moreover, the details of the result would (probably) be dependent on thread-scheduling order.

> My goal is to use either atomic or critical in openMP and achieve the same result as when I use firstprivate(state) in the following code

You can't.  As already described, although you could use `critical` sections to resolve your data races, the resulting series of computations is *different* from that obtained by `firstprivate(state)`, and moreover dependent on thread scheduling.  There is no justification for expecting identical results.

Additionally, putting critical sections in such a tight loop will almost surely kill any performance advantage from parallelization.  I would expect the parallel versions to quickly become slower than the serial one as the number of threads increases, maybe even with just two threads.