# OpenMP lock instruction in a function called by a parallelised loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, locking, openmp, atomic

I have a function that I call in a parallelised for loop. Everything in this function can be done in parallel, except for one variable incrementation that need to be locked. I tried to put `#pragma omp atomic` before the instruction, but it seems that since the function is only called in a parallel loop, and not parellised itself, the compiler calls an error: `error: ‘#pragma’ is not allowed here`.

My code looks like this (c++):

```cpp
class MyClass {
private:
  int **data;
  int data_size;

public:
  size_t myFunc(int r, int i) {
    int n = longFunc(...); // Long code that can be done in parallel if needed
    for (int j = 0; j < data_size; j++) {
      #pragma omp atomic // error: ‘#pragma’ is not allowed here
      data[r][j] += n + data[i][i] + i;  // This part cannot be parallelised
    }

    return n;
  }
  /* ... */
};

int main() {
  MyClass s;

  int row_to_change = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    size_t n = s.myFunc(row_to_change, i); // Parallel calls to the function
    /* ... */
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Any idea how I could keep the main part of `myFunc` possibly parallelised, but lock threads on the modification of the member `data`?

Comment: Is anything else in your parallelized loop reading `data`? Because from the code it seems like the row `data[i]` is always only accessed by one thread and therefore doesn't need atomicity

Comment: Looking at the code as posted, I agree with @homer, but if you do need atomicity there is always `std::mutex`.  Also, why aren't you using `std::vector` here?

Comment: @PaulSanders OpenMP has its own mutex / critical sections : see `#pragma omp critical` for example. Generally, it is better to avoid mixing OpenMP with parallelism-related C++ objects/constructs if possible.

Comment: Atomics access are far more expense than usual access on most CPUs (especially mainstream x86-64 ones). It is better to use them with care. One big lock on area of an array can be cheaper if needed (i.e. certainly not here). Besides `int**` is not efficient. You should flatten your 2D array and use a flatten indexing (i.e. `i*n+j`). With a flatten array, you may need to use `size_t` for large array though.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your advice. I saw about `#pragma omp critical`, but I’ve read here that it may not always be the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237293/13175624. It seemed to me that `#pragma omp atomic` was more adequate here

Comment: @Homer512 You are right, I tried to reproduce a simple example of my problem, but actually it is more complex, and the data matrix is written in every case for each iteration. My example was bad, I edited it.

Comment: Is it really just a sum or did you simplify the right-hand-side of the expression? Also, is anything reading `data` inside the parallelized code? The trouble is that with parallelization, the critical section will be executed with a random shuffle of `i` values. This will change the order of operations on `data` and the results, even if you ensure atomicity.

Comment: @Homer512 It is simplified but still just a sum. The actual operation looks like this:
`for (size_t i = 0; i < cur_gen_id; ++i) {
      mui.setInter(cur_gen_id, i, core_suffixes.getNbDistinctKMers() + s2v.size() + mui.getInter(cur_gen_id, i));`
Where `mui.setInter(i, j, v) { mui[i][j] = v; }` and `cur_gen_id` is the equivalent of `row_to_change` in my example.
Nothing reads `data` in the parallelised code, it just computes things to store in `data`. The order does not matter, as long as each threads result is taken into account by the next thread.

Comment: It looks like there might be an edge-case where `i == r` and `r == j`. In that case you probably want the read from `data[i][i]` to be part of the same critical section which cannot be achieved using one atomic, I think. In general it might help to put he calculation `n + data[i][i] + i` into a different line than the atomic update to better visualize what is happening.

Comment: My concern, supported by paleonix, is that correctness cannot be achieved regardless of whether `atomic` or `critical` is used. Just to humour my concerns, what happens if you put a `#pragma omp critical` before the line you want to have atomic? I know it will be slow, but are the results still correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out that my problem came from two factors:

- first, I forgot a semi-colon on the instruction before the `#pragma omp atomic`
- second, my command below `#pragma omp atomic` was of the form `r > j ? data[r][j] += ... : data[j][r] += ... ;`. And `atomic` can only accepts some syntax: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801012/13175624)

Thanks for everyone's time and sorry for posting a dumb question (even though the replies helped me solve my problem!)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not answering your real question, but rather correcting a mis-apprehension.
You state that "since the function is only called in a parallel loop, and not parellised itself, the compiler calls an error: error: ‘#pragma’ is not allowed here."

However, that is simply wrong. Provided you compile with OpenMP enabled, you can use an OpenMP atomic operation anywhere, it does not have to be visible to the compiler that the code is inside any parallelism at all.

Consider code like this:-

```
void lockedIncr(int *p)
{
  #pragma omp atomic
  (*p)++;
}
```

Since we're compiling that completely on its own, the compiler clearly cannot know the context of where it will be invoked.

If you look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/M88z96W9a) on Compiler Explorer, you can see it being successfully compiled for X86_64, and generating the code one would expect:-

```
lockedInc(int*):
        lock add        DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
        ret
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It might helps me understand why I get this error. It seems that not matter what I do, the compiler tells me that pragma is not allowed here. I didn't find anything about this error, do you have any idea why I get it?

Comment: @Kiffikiffe Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What compiler(-version) are you using?

Comment: @paleonix Something like https://godbolt.org/z/Y6Ez5Psro is my attempt at fixing up the code given to make it compilable. It compiles fine (with X86_64 GCC13.2), and has the atomic op in it... So you are right that we definitely need to know more about the OP's environment...

Comment: @JimCownie That's basically the same I did. And it compiled with all compilers that I tried or at least only failed for other reasons.

Comment: Oh that's neat; I didn't know C with OpenMP could portably do something equivalent to C++20 `std::atomic_ref<int>` and do an atomic RMW on a plain `int` object.  The other options I know about are the [GNU C builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) that the C++ `std::atomic<>` and `atomic_ref` library classes use on compilers that support them, like `__atomic_fetch_add(p, 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED)`